# Afin de ne pas changer d’avis, (afin de) ne pas hésiter

Tags: prépositions

Bonjour,

> Un frisson à peine perceptible parcourt mon dos, mais je chasse toutes
> les traces d’angoisse naissante de mon esprit, **afin de** ne pas
> changer d’avis, **afin de** ne pas hésiter.

Est-il possible d'omettre le deuxième "afin de", avant "ne pas hésiter" ?

Comment: *mais je chasse toutes les traces d'angoisse qui naissent dans mon esprit*

Comment: @jlliagre Pourquoi "angoisse naissante" est incorrecte ?

Comment: Peut-être pas incorrect mais bizarre, on s'attend à "naissant de mon esprit". Ce pourrait être aussi : *chasser de mon esprit toutes les traces d'angoisse qui y naissent*.

Answer (score 2):

Tu peux omettre le deuxième **afin** et c'est même une bonne idée, mais il faut laisser le **de** :

> [...], afin de ne pas changer d'avis, de ne pas hésiter.

Comment: Merci, et si j'omets ausse le "de", ce sera une faute ? Mais j'ai l'impression qu'il faut le laisser.

Comment: Peut-être pas une faute, mais ça demandera un effort de compréhension.